# Synced TV Shows Not Appearing in iPhone 'Videos'

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, video

I have tried syncing several episodes of a TV show (from a DVD ripped via Handbrake) to my iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3.2.  However, when I open "Videos" and look at the TV Shows tab, I do not see them.  I see other shows I have synced, but not this particular show.  iTunes lists the videos as being on the device.  And, in fact, if I go to Settings->Usage->Manage Storage->Videos I see that they're there!  They just don't appear in the Videos app on my phone.

Anyone seen anything like this before?  Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked in the Home Videos tab of the Videos app?

Comment: Yes, it's not listed.  The videos themselves are categorized as "TV Shows" and appear as such in iTunes and in Settings.